# What can we say about the number of unique roots of an infinite family of polynomials?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, dynamical-systems, fractals

Context: I saw the following problem on a discord server I'm in[image: math problem clearly framed as a meme]

Now, this is an obvious meme, but it's a really interesting question so I started working on it with some other people in a math discord. A fairly elementary simplification of the problem is to define the family of polynomials $p_1(c) = c$, $p_2(c) = c^2 + c$, $p_3(c) = \left(c^2 + c\right)^2 + c$, where, in general $p_n = p_{n - 1}^2 + c$.

If $c_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of any $p_n$, then $c_0$ only kills finitely many people, because iteratively applying $f$ with that choice of $c$ eventually returns you to $0$. However, this only gets you a subset of all the values of $c$ that work; in particular, this only gives you the values of $c$ which result in a loop that passes through $0$, which not all loops will. For example, choosing $c = -2$ gives the loop $0, -2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...$, so $-2$ solves the original problem but won't be the root of any $p_i$. We can make sure we have all the solutions by considering the roots to a difference of two of the $p_i$, since if $c$ is a root to $p_n(x) - p_m(x)$ where $n \neq m$, then clearly there is a cycle because two distinct numbers of iterations of $f$ return the same output.

At this point, we got stuck, and there are two natural questions

(1) What can we say about the roots of these polynomials? Are there infinitely many distinct roots? Are these uniformly bounded, and if not, are they nicely bounded by some function of $n$? Are the roots all isolated, or are there accumulation points?

And of course, the original problem:

(2) Is there a nice way to describe the set of all $c$ which are a root of some $p_i$ or which are the root of some $p_i - p_j$ for $i \neq j$?

I've tagged the question abstract-algebra and dynamical-systems because the questions about the roots seems algebraic, and the original problem seems like a dynamical systems problem. Please let me know if there are other tags which fit better.

Comment: I changed yours tags to some I found more revelant

Comment: To answer the image question, choosing c=0 kill just one guy.

Comment: I feel like you should just read through the Wiki page on the Mandelbrot set and chase a couple of the links.

Comment: Additionally, user Claude has lots of pages on the general topic and https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2018-08-06_enumeration_of_misiurewicz_points.html on the enumeration of these points (with a small error in the first formula). There also the claim is repeated that the (proper, with pre-period) Misiurewicz points are dense in the Mandelbrot fractal (the boundary curve).

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks for the bug report, should be fixed now (you might need to force a browser refresh).